# Unable to save as word document in another location

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim wrdApp, wrdDoc
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim Path As String
   
       
    Path = "C:\Rohan\Automations\CM Plan Automation\Upload\"
    filename = Range("C4").Text
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .documents.Open "C:\Rohan\Automations\CM Plan Automation\Engagement Name_Configuration Management Plan.docx"
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A

                .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  'Replacements from col B

                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False

                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            Next
        
        End With
        
        
        .SaveAs2 filename:=filename & _
FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
        
        '.Quit SaveChanges:=True
         
        '.Quit
        
        '.SaveAs2 Filename:=("file name goes here"), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
        
        
       '.SaveAs filename:=filename & ".docx"
        
       '.SaveAs2 filename:="C:\Rohan\Automations\CM Plan Automation\Upload\" & ".docx",
        'FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
        
        
        
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: All I see is code with no explanation of what your problem is. Do you get an error? If so, what is the error description, and on which line does it occur? Have you checked that you are supplying the full path and file name? Is it a file permissions problem? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71171179/edit) your question and provide detail.

Comment: Unable to save as, it gives error as Document not open or give 438 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `SaveAs` code comes in the `With msWord` block and is missing a document object.

Your issue is related to your use of late binding (declaring Word as object). There is little value to using late binding in this instance. Using it has meant that the compiler doesn't know your code is wrong. It has also robbed you of the use of IntelliSense and access to the Word object library in the Object Browser.

The only advantage to late binding is version independence, i.e. you can write code in a newer version, and it will theoretically work in an older one. But that advantage is lost unless you also use late binding for the host application code as Office is usually installed as a package. It is better to use early binding when working with other Office applications and reserve late binding for other commonly used libraries, e.g. ADO or XML.

Additionally, you should avoid the use of `ActiveDocument` when your code is opening a specific document. Use a variable instead, as below.

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim msWord As Word.Application, wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim ws As Worksheet, itm As Range
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim Path As String
   
       
    Path = "C:\Rohan\Automations\CM Plan Automation\Upload\"
    filename = Range("C4").Text
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        Set wrdDoc = .documents.Open("C:\Rohan\Automations\CM Plan Automation\Engagement Name_Configuration Management Plan.docx")

        With wrdDoc.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False

            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col A

                .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  'Replacements from col B

                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            Next
        
        End With
        
        wrdDoc.SaveAs2 filename:=filename, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
        
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```